# How to declare an object with un-named primitives in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I need to represent the following array in swagger-2.0, but am unsure how to do it, since I cannot figure out how to declare 'un-named' properties.

For example, here's what I need to define:

coords: [
    [
      37.782984,
      -122.420973
    ],
    [
      37.772309,
      -122.418555
    ],
...
]

How can I define these array-entries in swagger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you model it as an array of arrays with two items, it should look like this:

```
parameters:
  - name: coords
    in: body
    schema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          type: number
        maxItems: 2
        minItems: 2
```

Comment: Perfect ... forgot that I could use minItems/maxItems to do this. Thanks !!